# Is it possible to get Twitter Trends just for top 20% of users?

Tags: api, twitter

I wonder would it be possible to build and app or website where twitter trends would be displayed on different, bit more useful way. Does Twitter API supports such queries and whether it might be possible to run analysis on our own servers, just use Twitter API to get data. If we could use data only from most influential users and create new Trend list I think we might come with much more useful Trends than we have now.

Comment: No, Twitter doesn't provide that sort of focused data through the API.

Comment: Won't the top 20% twitter users will yield a similarly smelly cesspool of tweets?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [Pulling data from Twitter](http://activeintelligence.org/sebastien/2011/04/08/pulling-data-from-twitter-tools/)